# Accessing in-memory HSQLDB in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hsqldb

I am using in-memory HSQLDB in my web application to store and retrieve data. When i try to access my database manually using Data Source Explorer in Eclipse  it is creating a new connection and it is not retrieving the existing DB.

Following are the steps i used to connect

the connection details in web app is

```
database.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
database.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:mem\:pizza
database.username=sa
database.password=
```

while connecting from Data Source Explorer in Eclipse the details are

```
Connection URL     jdbc:hsqldb:mem:pizza
Database Name      pizza
UserID             sa
```

It is successfully connected, But it is not referring to the existing DB.

I have checked the same using file storage it worked fine and i am able to connect using "Data Source Explorer" as well.

Is it possible to connect in-memory HSQLDB using "Data Source Explorer" in eclipse.

Please help me on this

Thanks in Advance,

Regards,
Vibin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the database from both inside and outside Eclipse during development, you need to run a server externally. See the Guide below. You CAN run a server that serves an in-memory database. You connect to this server using the normal server connection method.

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html